# OSX Cocoa Book recommendation for an iOS Developer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I'm an experienced iOS developer, and I understand the basic differences between iOS and OSX development in theory, but have not written a single app for OSX. Next week, I plan to begin my first OSX app. This weekend, I have a long road trip... so I'm hoping someone can recommend a good book for learning OSX/Cocoa development, considering my existing knowledge (eg, I'd really rather not putz around with "Here's a NSString!" or other such Hello-world-esque approaches for newbies to Objective C).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be inclined to pick up [Beginning Lion OSX Apps Development](http://www.apress.com/9781430237204) (a book from Apress because I had a good experience with them for iOS). The reviews on Amazon aren't the greatest but the worst reviews have complaints about the book's poor index. Someone who had iOS development experience but wanted to switch over to mac (someone like you) gave it a 4-star rating.

In all honesty though, I would opt for guides and Apple documentation. If you are going to have access to an iPad on your road trip, I would recommend you download some of Apple's programming guides to iBooks and read them during your trip. If you want examples step-by-step however, and need help overcoming a learning curve, I find Apress books to be solid.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about moving from iOS to Mac development.

Comment: My bad, just edited my answer.

Comment: Cool, and I stripped out your earlier answer. No reason to have it remain.

Comment: Good answer! My iPad was exactly what I was planning on bringing, and I was going to bring whatever PDF resources I could find in the OSX dev portal, but it can be nice to have a well-tailored resource like a book, as well ;)